# How to change special price for store view

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Is there any option in magento to set special price for store view , I have used Store View Pricing module  but I have some special price which will be different in store views.

Answer (score 0):

By design, you cannot change the price attributes at a store view level. The price scope can be global or website.
And this is kind of logical since a store view is just a "face" of a website. Customers should not have to pay a different price depending on the language they speak or the currency they use.

Comment: As a matter of fact they should as viewing in a different language should change the currency as well.

Comment: you can have different currencies for different store views, but the prices are calculated based on the currency exchange rates.